# Android stops connecting to local hosts

Tags: wi-fi

Droid, v 24.91.5.  Router(1) = TC C1100T,  hardwire to second router(2) (at some distance).  I power up my Droid and connect to 192.168.0.xx (a web page), works fine.  Some time later I attempt to connect to 192.168.0.xx and it times out as unavail.  At any time I can connect to anything in the WWW cloud, just not anything 192.168.0.xx.  Sometime I can power off/on and it works, sometimes not.  I can change wifi to the second router(2) and it works.  It's not the TC as it's the second router(1) I'm using.

Comment: You need to configure your routers. What's your Android question?

Comment: I have a laptop that works just fine.  I can connect to any of my 192.168.0.xxx devices.  At the exact same time & place my phone times out.  And the phone connect to anything in the cloud without a problem.